# concatenate more than 4 string in loop at "match" on SIFT via bash

Tags: string, bash, loops, concatenation, sift

a moment ago, i looked up SIFT algorithm to process my images..

if you ever using SIFT from http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/ there is an executable file named "match" to get correlation of one to another images..

this is the example..

```
./match -im1 book.pgm -k1 book.key -im2 scene.pgm -k2 scene.key > out.pgm
```

so..

i realized that i need to speed up my process using bash script.. to correlate more than two images even if the default "match" only accepted 2 images and 2 keys related on that images.. then..

this is my code..

```
i = 1 
s = ""

for item in *.key
do
    s += "-im$((i)) ${item%.*}.pgm -k$((i++)) $item"
done

./match s > out.pgm
```

And now the scenario,

based on my code,

if I used echo in line 6

```
echo "-im$((i)) ${item%.*}.pgm -k$((i++)) $item"
```

and commented the last line

```
#! ./match s > out.pgm
```

then I got the list that I wanted..

BUT..

if I exactly run my code {based on the answers which I commented} there is a problem that faced in my terminal window

```
Error: Invalid command line argument: -im3
```

are there can help me please?? 
^^

i am so sorry if my English bad..

Comment: How is this a SIFT question? This is just a bash and concatenation question that happens to use the output of a SIFT program.

Comment: my lecturer said that SIFT can used to give information about an object from multiple image (not just compare 2 images with their correlated keys), so that why I wanna know how to do it.. 
the progress about that, you can see my answer.. ^^.. thanks for commenting..

Comment: may be you can guest right title for my question.. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I check the "match" code in file match.c in line 32 until 52

> ```
> /* Parse command line arguments and read given files.  The command
>    line must specify two input images and two files of keypoints
>    using command line arguments as follows:
>       match -im1 i1.pgm -k1 k1.key -im2 i2.pgm -k2 k2.key > result.v
> */
> while (++arg < argc) {
>   if (! strcmp(argv[arg], "-im1")) 
> im1 = ReadPGMFile(argv[++arg]);
>   else if (! strcmp(argv[arg], "-im2")) 
> im2 = ReadPGMFile(argv[++arg]);
>   else if (! strcmp(argv[arg], "-k1"))
> k1 = ReadKeyFile(argv[++arg]);
>   else if (! strcmp(argv[arg], "-k2"))
> k2 = ReadKeyFile(argv[++arg]);
>   else
> FatalError("Invalid command line argument: %s", argv[arg]);
> }
> if (im1 == NULL || im2 == NULL || k1 == NULL || k2 == NULL)
>   FatalError("Command line does not specify all images and keys.");
> FindMatches(im1, k1, im2, k2);
> exit(0);
> ```

at http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/siftDemoV4.zip

I should add some variables in that codes or use a collection to complemented all variables.. cause my real codes is in Java.. (^^)9

anyway.. thanks for the answer at bash script.. all of the answer is usefull.. (^^)v

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not allowed in variables assignations, so :

```
i=1 
s=

for item in *.key
do
    s+="-im$i ${item%.*}.pgm -k$((i++)) $item"
done

./match "$s" > out.pgm
```

Comment: thanks.. but.. there are showed another problem in my terminal window.. it's say:

Error: Invalid command line argument: s

Comment: where {s} in this case is all of parameter which used in "match"

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of accumulating command options in a single string will fail if any of the names of any of the `*.key` files contain a space. In `bash`, it's better to use an array.

```
i=1 
s=()

for item in *.key
do
    s+=( "-im$i" "${item%.*}.pgm" "-k$i" "$item" )
    ((i++))
done

./match "${s[@]}" > out.pgm
```

Comment: no, <code>-im3</code> is  parameter to represented the third image followed with the name of image file..

Comment: Then I'm afraid this is not a `bash` issue, but an issue with the `match` program itself.

Comment: Try quoting all the arguments when adding them to `s` (I've updated the answer to reflect this). (No idea if that's helpful, but I'm trying to think of `bash`-related issues that could confuse `match` when it reads its arguments.)

Comment: thanks, but it does not change anything.. may be I need some SIFT expert first.. ^^